# Trying to get command line arguments to work with my code but have an error - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror, null-pointer

Hi everyone I'm pretty new to programming and python, but I've nearly got this piece of code working. I just need to figure out how to get the arguments called in the command line to work with my code. What I tried did not work, which is this part:

> tree.find("./PLANT/[COMMON='%s'" % sys.argv[3]):

Here is my whole code:

```
import os
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import sys

# changes to the correct directory of each different environment
os.chdir(os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop'))

file = "plant_catalog.xml"
tree = ET.parse(file)

# Finds section by plant name and adjusts the price according to argument
 for plant in tree.find("./PLANT/[COMMON='%s'" % sys.argv[3]):
    if plant.tag == "PRICE":
        plant.text = float(plant.text) * sys.argv[4]
        plant.text = str(plant.text)
    print(plant.text)

tree.write("plant_catalog.xml")
```

Here are the errors thrown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:/Users/cader/PycharmProjects/ModifyML/ModifyML.py", line 14, in 
>      for plant in tree.find(name):
>    File "C:\Users\cader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementTree.py", line 653, in find
>      return self._root.find(path, namespaces)
>    File "C:\Users\cader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 307, in find
>      return next(iterfind(elem, path, namespaces), None)
>    File "C:\Users\cader\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\xml\etree\ElementPath.py", line 300, in iterfind
>      result = select(context, result)
>   TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

I'm really sorry if this is badly formatted I created an account just to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that the result of `ET.parse(file)` is a null-pointer (there is no result).

I'd advise you to check that `parse()` function. In case you have issues, you can edit your question and add the source code of that function.

Comment: While I don't fully understand what ET.parse(file) is doing for me, removing it causes it to not work in my code that does work.

I managed to get my code to work by changing my sys.argv[4] to float(sys.argv[4]) and realizing I was missing a bracket.